# How do I change the design of the alert box in Android studio webview?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I just started the Android Studio two days ago and I've never experienced Java before. However, I know the language to build a website. I've finished creating a hybrid app to render my website as an app in a `WebView`. I want to change the design and the title of `AlertDialog` from my WebView, how could I do it?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView WebView01 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebView01.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        WebView01.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = WebView01.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
        webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        WebView01.loadUrl("http://url");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials available online. You can create custom `AlertDialog` and you can give whatever design you want and load `WebView` on that `AlertDialog`

[create a custom dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562894/android-how-to-customize-alertdialog-dialog-an-spinner-titles)

[Android custom dialog example](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

[How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can I ask you to let me know that alert of web is a AlertDailog from the app?

Comment: No, `AlertDialog` in android and `Alert` in web both are different. Load `Webview` inside the `AlertDialog` and if you have `Alert` inside the webview then it not get effect and you can design that `Alert` using html and css..

Comment: I don't understand all the contents, but I think I know what you mean. Then, can I change Alert to AlertDialog? Because I know that I can not change a html and css using Alert.